# KeyError when trying to use dictionary generated from SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

This is a follow up question to one I asked a couple of days ago. At that point, I encountered the following error, when trying to use SQLITE to generate a dictionary in Python:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "transportation problem.py", line 20, in <module>
   I = set([i for (i,k) in d])
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This could be solved, thanks to the suggestions made by Andy Hayden worked fine at first, but when I implemented it into my code, I started getting the following error:

```
c[i,j,k] = cost[i,j] * weight[k]
KeyError: ((1, 2), 1)
```

I am not sure, what caused this error, but would be very glad if somebody could point me in the right direction, of how I would be able to get this code to work. My code looks like follows:

```
#DISTANCE    
cur.execute('SELECT idcustomer,idproduct,demand FROM demand')
result = cur.fetchall()
for idcustomer,idproduct,demand in result:
      d[idcustomer,idproduct] = demand
      I = set([i for (i,k) in d.iteritems()])
      K = set([k for (i,k) in d.iteritems()])
#CAPACITY

cur.execute('select idfactory,capacity from factory')
result = cur.fetchall()
J, M = multidict(result)

produce = {1:[2,4], 2:[1,2,3], 3:[2,3,4]} 

#WEIGHT
cur.execute('SELECT idproduct,weight FROM product')
result = cur.fetchall()
K, weight = multidict(result)          

#COST
cur.execute('SELECT idcustomer,idfactory,distance FROM distance')
result = cur.fetchall()
for idcustomer,idfactory,distance in result:
    cost[idcustomer,idfactory] = distance

c = {}
for i in I:
    for j in J:
        for k in produce[j]:
            c[i,j,k] = cost[i,j] * weight[k]
```

The error is produced in the last line of this code. When I input the SQLITE data manually, and revert 'd.iteritems' back to 'd', the code works without a problem.

```
 produce = {1:[2,4], 2:[1,2,3], 3:[2,3,4]}  
 K, weight = multidict({1:5, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4})            
      cost = {(1,1):4,  (1,2):6, (1,3):9,        
              (2,1):5,  (2,2):4, (2,3):7,
              (3,1):6,  (3,2):3, (3,3):4,
              (4,1):8,  (4,2):5, (4,3):3,
              (5,1):10, (5,2):8, (5,3):4,
              }
      c = {}
      for i in I:
        for j in J:
           for k in produce[j]:
               c[i,j,k] = cost[i,j] * weight[k]
```

Any suggestions would again be more than welcome!

Edit:

Following a suggestion of @abarnert, I have added the values of I, J, K, weight and cost.

```
{'I': set([(1, 2), (5, 4), (1, 3), (3, 3), (5, 2), (4, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4), (5, 1), (4, 1), (2, 4), (4, 4), (5, 3)])}

{'J': [1, 2, 3]}

{'K': [1, 2, 3]}
{'weight': {1: 5.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 4.0}}
{'cost': {(1, 2): 6.0, (3, 2): 3.0, (1, 3): 9.0, (3, 3): 4.0, (5, 2): 8.0, (3, 1): 6.0, (2, 1): 5.0, (2, 3): 7.0, (4, 3): 3.0, (2, 2): 4.0, (5, 1): 10.0, (4, 2): 5.0, (4, 1): 8.0, (1, 1): 4.0, (5, 3): 4.0}}
```

Comment: This look strange for me "I = set([i for (i,k) in d.iteritems()])" don't you try just I = set(d)? and why is it in loop, d is accumulator, right? if so I=... and K=... should be after loop

Comment: Have you tried printing out the intermediate values right before the error? What's in `i`, `j`, `k`, `cost[i,j]`, and `weight[k]`? Even if you can't understand how that helps, it will likely give someone else the answer immediately.

Comment: I have done so, and appended the results to my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have KeyError as exceptions states:

```
for i in I:
    for j in J:
        for k in produce[j]:
            c[i,j,k] = cost[i,j] * weight[k]
```

here is `i` is tuple (idcustomer, idproduct) you create `I` in first loop, but cost have tuple `(idcustomer, idfactory)` as keys, so in last loop you trying get value from cost with tuple `((idcustomer, idproduct), whatever multidict returns)` and it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your suggestions I was finally able to figure out the solution.
I changed the following code:

```
  I = set([i for (i,k) in d.iteritems()])
  K = set([k for (i,k) in d.iteritems()])
```

To the code below:

```
  I = set([i for [i,j,k] in result])
  K = set([j for [i,j,k] in result])
```

The problem was that the former code produced incorrect results for two sets which I sought to create.